# Continuity of a certain matrix-like function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a finite set and let $M$ be a space of all probability measures on $X$. Let $f:X\to\Bbb R^{m\times m}$ be a random matrix and consider a function $c:M\to\Bbb R$ defined as
$$
  c(\mu) := \operatorname{Tr}(\langle \mu, f\rangle^{-1})
\quad
\text{with} \quad\langle \mu,f\rangle := \sum_{x\in X} f(x)\mu(\{x\}).
$$
Consider $c^* := \sup_{\mu\in M}c(\mu)$ and suppose there exists $\mu^*$ such that $c(\mu^*) = c^*$. Is it possible to show that $c$ is continuous at $\mu^*$? Here I assume $M$ is endowed with a total variation distance.

Comment: Have you tried to formulate this in terms of matrices?

Comment: @Norbert: not really, do you think the problem is well-suited for such framework? I understand, it is sufficient to show that $\langle \cdot,f\rangle^{-1}$ is continuous in certain points, but my experience with linear algebra is not that good.